# Gstreamer fails to delay linking some pads of GstTSDemux named demux to some pad of GstAacParse

Tags: audio, video, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

Please excuse me if its a naïve question as I'm kind of new to gstreamer development and facing below issue with implementing below pipeline

```
srtsrc -> tsdemux name=demux
   demux. -> audiopipeline -> mpegtsmux name=mux
   demux. -> videopipeline -> mux.
mux. -> srtsink
```

In above pipeline its expected to activate srtsrc for audio and video separately, so there can be delay activating between them, but then my pipeline fails to delay linking these streams separately

Actual error:

`subprojects/gstreamer/gst/parse/grammar.y:540:gst_parse_no_more_pads:<demux> warning: failed delayed linking some pad of GstTSDemux named demux to some pad of GstAacParse named aacparse0 WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTSDemux:demux: Delayed linking failed. Additional debug info: subprojects/gstreamer/gst/parse/grammar.y(540): gst_parse_no_more_pads (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTSDemux:demux: failed delayed linking some pad of GstTSDemux named demux to some pad of GstAacParse named aacparse0`

So, I think I know what causing this issue but don't know how to deal with it, any leads would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.